# AWS Serverless PDF download

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I would like to download a PDF file using a nodejs lambda function deployed in AWS. Please let me know the configurations to be provided in serverless settings.yaml file.

I am able to download PDF by making below configuration changes from console.

1) Add Content-Type as application/pdf 2) Map the response model for application/pdf=>Empty 3) Change the content handling in integration response from passthrough (default) to Convert to Binary. I am looking for options where these can be provided in serverless configuration file

I am looking for options where content handling and response model can be set using serverless

Below is the snippet from serverless.yml

```
 events:
  - http:
      path: /test
      method: get
      integration: lambda
      response:
       statusCodes:
        200:
         pattern: '' # Default response method
         headers:
          Content-Type: "'application/pdf'"
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you failed. We can help you from there.

Comment: i am able to set Content-Type response header, but not response model and content handling.

Comment: Put those in your question not as comments.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: and how does it look your serverless.yml ? did you add that response header? are you using lambda integration, or lambda-proxy integration type?

Comment: Updated the question. I am using lambda integration. tried giving contentHandling=CONVERT_TO_BINARY under http as well as under statusCode 200, but the value is not getting set in the integration response of API Gateway

Answer (score 4):

In your lambda function, you have to return a json object like that:

```
    {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf' },
      body: YOUR_PDF_base64_encoded_string,
      isBase64Encoded: true, // important
    };
```

then, you can use `serverless-apigw-binary` plugin to config APIGateway Binary Support or you can do it by manualy: Change APIGateway setting

[image: APIGateway Binary Support]

use `application/pdf` instead of my image mime types.